# Set a property value to 0, when creating a user

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I set the balance property to 0, when registering a new account on my create view in MVC. I want the balance to be 0 as default for the user who has just been registered!

```
namespace CSGO_MVC.Models
{
    public class SteamAccount
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long SteamId { get; set; }
        public Balance accountbalance { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool UserStatus { get; set; }
        public string TradeLink { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SteamAccount acc)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AccountRepo.Insert(acc);
        AccountRepo.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the _current_ default value of `Balance` that you are experiencing now?

Comment: What is your `Balance` type?

Comment: Set it in the create method? Like `acc.accountBalance.value = 0` where value = the actual property name that needs to be 0

Answer (score 1):

You show no details about `Balance`, I'll assume it is a class similar to this:

```
public class Balance
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to assign the `accountbalance` with a properly initialized `Balance` object, like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    acc.accountbalance = new Balance { Value = 0 };
    AccountRepo.Insert(acc);
    AccountRepo.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
// ...
```

In fact the default value of an int is `0` already, but I often like things being done explicitly.